# Is 'show' a normal S4 generic function?

Tags: r, show, r-s4, generic-function

I'm trying to create a method for my class, which inherits from data.frame. I was originally hoping just to inherit the 'show' method from data.frame as well, but I'm also fine with writing my own. I defined my class and 'show' method as follows:

```
setClass("SCvec", representation(auth = "character",
    dev = "character",
    sensor = "character",
    channel = "character",
    starttime = "character",
    endtime = "character"),
    contains="data.frame")
setMethod("show", signature(x="SCvec"), function(x) print(x))
```

when I type `show` in the R console, it prints out:

standardGeneric for "show" defined from package "methods"

```
function (object) 
standardGeneric("show")
<bytecode: 0x0396bee8>
<environment: 0x0393ab60>
Methods may be defined for arguments: object
Use  showMethods("show")  for currently available ones.
(This generic function excludes non-simple inheritance; see ?setIs)
```

So it sure looks like I don't need to turn it into a generic using StandardGeneric() myself. but when I run my `setMethod("show", signature(x="SCvec"), function(x) print(x))` line, I get the error

```
Error in match.call(definition, call, expand.dots) : 
  unused argument(s) (x = c("SCvec", ""))
```

I've defined this method just like I would define any other one. Why does this method definition not work? Is 'show' different than other generic functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `show` takes an argument `object`, so you would need to define your signature and function definition with respect to that formal argument:

```
setMethod("show", signature(object="SCvec"), function(object) print(object))
```

You can also see other methods that are defined for `show` by typing in

```
showMethods(show)
```

And this shows you that all the other methods are defined in terms of the class of `object` as well.

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake on my part... all of the methods I had been defining previously took 'x' as the argument, and I just copied and pasted my code for 'show'.

Comment: `getGeneric("show")` provides an interactive look at the generic signature.