# setMethod for a Class in R

Tags: r, class, methods

I am trying to create a method for the class "subject" using the Generic method "summary".  However, I get an error message.  Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to correct it?   Thank you.

```
      setGeneric("summary")

      setMethod("summary",
      c(x = "subject"),
      function(x){"This is summary for subject class"})
```

The error message is the following:

```
      Error in match.call(definition, call, expand.dots, envir) : 
      unused argument (x = c("subject", ""))
```

I have used the setMethod to create a method for the class "subject" using the Generic method "print" as follows:

```
      setMethod("print",
            c(x = "subject"),
            function(x){
                 if (length(x$id) > 0){
                       paste0("Subject ID: ", unique(x$id))}
                 else {"NULL"}
             })
```

The aforementioned code is executed without errors.  I can not understand what is the difference between the two cases.

Comment: I'd recommend starting here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Comment: I would appreciate if you could be more specific

Answer (score 5):

The code works if x is replaced with "object".  I.e.:

```
     setMethod("summary",
     c(object = "subject"),
     function(object){"This is summary for subject class"})
```

There is some related information here: 
[Is 'show' a normal S4 generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439357/is-show-a-normal-s4-generic-function)

Hope that helps.